# How can I disable clusterization feature for `MGLSymbolStyleLayer`?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

**Environment**

- `Mapbox-iOS-SDK 3.7.8`

I have tried to disable clusterization for `MGLSymbolStyleLayer` with `MGLShapeSource`.

After `MGLMapView` has loaded I make `MGLSymbolStyleLayer`

```
private func makeSymbolLayer(withId identifier: String, style: MGLStyle) {
    let options = [MGLShapeSourceOption.clustered: false as NSNumber]
    let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: identifier, features: [], options: options)

    let layer = MGLSymbolStyleLayer(identifier: identifier, source: source)

    style.addSource(source)
    style.addLayer(layer)
}
```

Then when I obtain data from a server I fill a shape. I create features with different icons.

```
source.shape = MGLShapeCollectionFeature(shapes: loadedFeatures)
```

But anyway the clusterization is  always ON.
Is it possible disable a clusterization for `MGLSymbolStyleLayer`?

Comment: Which version of the Mapbox Maps SDK for iOS are you seeing this issue with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not been able to reproduce this issue, but `options` is optional. Therefore, you should be able to set it to `nil` in order and not see clustering.

`let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: identifier, features: [], options: nil)`

Some features may hidden to avoid icon overlap. If you would like to allow icon overlap, set [`iconAllowsOverlap`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/4.1.1/Classes/MGLSymbolStyleLayer.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLSymbolStyleLayer(py)iconAllowsOverlap) to `YES`.

Comment: Yea. Setting `iconAllowsOverlap` to `YES` has solved my issue. 
It was my mistake. I have thought that it was cluster behaviour but It wasn't cluster.